# ImageView width and height does not work

Tags: android, imageview

I use an ImageView in my Relative Layout. 
This is the Code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jpicture_imageView"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jName_TextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"           
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

For testing purpose, I set width and height to 10dp, but the picture is always it's original size.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: post complete layout

Comment: Where is your src=??
It suggest you're doing some extra manipulations in code. 
Post this view parent XML and maybe the code where you set the image?

Comment: remove android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" or 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this kind of resizing stuff try going from crap and adding attributes little by little (when you are not sure what you are doing ;)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jpicture_imageView"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jName_TextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"           
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

This part can be the problem :

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/jName_TextView"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

You align the view left and right,  below another view and center vertically.

With the attibutes fitXY and adjustViewBounds the view will not be only 10dp. Try changing those attributes.

Delete them and add them again one by one to see the changes for yourself

Answer (score 0):

the part with 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

was the problem. Removing one of them fixed it.

Thanks for yur answers.

Best regards,
Peter